# Bitcoin mining specification to write own mining application

Tags: blockchain, client, block, mining-theory, solo-mining

Where can I find the design specifications to write my own mining application for mining bitcoin.
More I read I find there are number of implementations and some pools only work with specific mining software and there is no way to find single (kind of) wiki that explains the development design specifications.

Till now I find 2 protocols GetWork (which is obsolete now) and Stratum. But within stratum I find input and output implementation varies with different mining applications.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I've got some basic functions but I'm unable to find a good primer on crafting transactions (including coinbase transactions) and submitting blocks.

Comment: After a few years, I still don't know very well. Even Bitcoin core has removed the code that mines new blocks in 2016, and it seems that there is no reference implementation anymore.